# How to add add ons to Orange3

Tags: pandas, orange

I am using pandas to do some data analysis. Others in my company are wanting to process data in a similar fashion, but won't want to use a programming language to do it. After significant googling, I found Orange, which has the perfect interface for what I'm wanting people to do. However, the widgets don't do the types of tasks we're looking at. So, I decided to see if I could write my own widgets for Orange to do the tasks.

I'm trying to use Orange3; this seems like the best bet when I'm using WinPython. I must say that going through the documentation for widget creation (for Orange2) and the code for the Orange3 widgets is rather impressive - very nicely written and easy to use to implement what I'm wanting to do.

After writing a couple of widgets, how do I get them into Orange3? the widget creation tutorial is for Orange2 (in Python 2.7), and I haven't got it to work for Orange3.

My project is at the moment rather small:

```
dir/
  orangepandas/
    __init__.py
    owPandasFile.py
    pandasQtTable.py
  setup.py
```

setup.py currently contains the following:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='orangepandas',
      version='0.1',
      packages=['orangepandas'],
      entry_points={'Orange.widgets': 'orangepandas = orangepandas'}
      )
```

When I run python setup.py install on this and then try opening Orange3 canvas, I don't see my shiny new widget in its new group.

Answer (score 2):

After tracing through how Orange3 imports external libraries, it seems that Orange relies on the actual widget file existing, rather than being inside a egg (zipped) file. Adding

```
zip_safe=False
```

to the setup options allowed Orange3 to import the widgets correctly. Orange3 uses `os.path.exists` in `cache_can_ignore` in canvas/registry/discovery.py to detect if the path exists at all, and if it doesn't, it doesn't try to import it. Using `zip_safe=False` makes sure that the addon stays uncompressed so that the individual files are accessible.

(For the next person who tries to do what I was doing.)